# How to set binding memory limits in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I would like to have Snakemake set binding memory limits for individual rules. Based on the snakemake documentation, `mem_mb` argument seems like it would work, but the job uses more memory than I've allocated.

Here's a simple rule that uses several GB of memory. I would like the rule to be stopped once it hits the memory limit, but it completes without issue.

```py
rule:
    output:
        "a"
    threads: 1
    resources:
        mem_mb = 100
    shell:
        """
        python3 -c 'import numpy; x=numpy.ones(1_000_000_000)'
        touch a
        """
```

Is it possible to make this limit bind? I'd like a solution that's portable, working for Windows and Linux. I'm using snakemake locally, not with a batch scheduler or container setup.

Comment: "ressources" in snakemake are not related to actual ressource usage. They are an arbitrary value that you assign to the whole snakemake run, and snakemake will not run simultaneously jobs whose total in that ressource goes above the assigned amount for the run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have absolutely no experience with this, so I can't really say if this is recommended or works well across platforms, but this seems to work on my computer (Ubuntu):

```
rule all:
    input:
        "a"

rule:
    output:
        "a"
    threads: 1
    resources:
        mem_mb = 100
    params:
        max_mem=lambda wildcards, resources: resources.mem_mb * 1024
    shell:
        """
        ulimit -v {params.max_mem}
        python3 -c 'import numpy; x=numpy.ones(1_000_000_000)'
        touch a
        """
```

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120765/memory-limiting-solutions-for-greedy-applications-that-can-crash-os) for more info.

I don't believe SnakeMake offers an "out of the box" solution for this.

Comment: This is great for Ubuntu! If anyone has ideas for Windows, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with this myself but note that the use of the `resources` directive should be accompanied by the command line option `--resources`. In your case, you could execute:

```
snakemake -j 10 --resources mem_mb=500
```

and this will ensure that jobs running at the same time will not exceed mem_mb = 500 (and at most 10 jobs run at the same time). However, a rule with more than mem_mb=500 will still run as a single job. To prevent that I think Maarten-vd-Sande's solution is the best I can think of.